# How can I load an HTML5 page into my HTML5 page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I am making a simple static app in HTML5.

What I am doing now is that I have one single long page in which I have thousands of lines of code.

I am currently doing this to go to another page:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <label for="heading">History</label>
    <a href="#module_a" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-transition="flip">History</a>
    <a href="module_b" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">Remote Control</a>
</div>
```

...and then I have module_a & module_b as follow...

```
<div id="module_a" data-role="page">
    //content
</div>
```

...and same for module_b

Both divs are in same page so my page looks very bad.

What I want to is that I need same functionality but I dont want my divs that is module_a and module_b in the same page.

I want to create different pages for that and then load it as I am going so that my main page looks clear.

Comment: Edited for spelling and formatting, plus I changed your tags based on what I believe you were asking. If they're wrong let me know.

Comment: Thomas: You forgot about "than" vs. "then". ;-)

Comment: Do you want to separate the html files or the final page? If you want to switch the content dynamically you can use display:none in either module_a or module_b. If you want to separate html files you can do sommething like innerHTML = <http get query>

Comment: @Antoine yes i want to separate html files that is one page for module_a and another page for module_b

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I gather what you're asking correctly you want AJAX. When you click on one of the links/buttons you need a javascript code which will send a request to get the HTML of another page and load it into place on the page.

The best way to do this is to use jQuery. It has this really helpful function called `load()` which does EXACTLY what you need. http://api.jquery.com/load/

It looks like this:

```
$('#containerWhereYouWantTheContentToLoad').load('http://url.to/content/you/want/to/load.html');
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

1. Put each of your modules in their own file.
2. Amend the links to the modules so that they link to the module files.
3. Replace the modules in your original file with an `<iframe>` tag.
4. Add `onclick` event handler to each link that sets the `src` attribute of the `<iframe>` to the URL of the module’s file (and returns `false`, so that the link isn’t followed).

However, you’ve got more scope for doing stuff with the HTML that you load if you go with AJAX [as suggested by @ThomasClayson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11258425/20578).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried AJAX?

```
 $.ajax({
   url: 'seperate_page.html',
   success: function(data) {
     $('#module_b').html(data);
   }
 });
```

From how I understood the question, this will solve your problem.. hope it helps